# What did Donna mean when she told Harvey "she wants more"?

Tags: plot-explanation, suits

In the Season 6 finale episode of *Suits*, Donna told Harvey that "she wants more"? What was she referring to, her job position or their personal life relation?

Comment: My Typo mistake!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show creator Aaron Korsh explains that this will be explored next season...

> “Donna, a part of her was awakened and we left her wanting more and that is an open question,” Korsh told Deadline. “Does she mean more work-wise? Does she mean more with Harvey? Season seven is a platform to explore that a little bit more.”
>
> "I had a discussion with Sarah Rafferty about that scene, and we decided that **10 different people could watch it and come up with 10 different thoughts that were going through Donna’s mind in that moment**," Korsh said. "I think in that moment it obviously touches on: does she want more with Harvey? And, regardless of whether she wants more with Harvey or not, does she want more out of life? And what does she means with ‘I don’t want the money?’ I don’t think she means she doesn’t want money, obviously, everybody wants money."
>
> <sup>More at Source - [USANetwork.com](http://www.usanetwork.com/suits/blog/what-did-donna-mean-when-she-said-she-wanted-more-suits-boss-weighs-in)</sup>

Comment: Revealed as that Donna needs something more from Harvey, its both personal and professional (no spoilers I guess..)